# Is there any way to write Hebrew in the Windows Console?

Tags: .net, unicode, utf-8, console, hebrew

Is there any way to write Hebrew in the Windows Console?

I tried the following:

```
Console.OutputEncoding = new UTF8Encoding(false);
Console.WriteLine("\u05D0\u05D1");
Console.ReadLine();
```

but instead of "אב" it writes some other Unicode character, that're not in the Hebrew ABC.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can call `chcp` command before your program, you can change the codepage to Hebrew and then your characters will be readable. There is an interesting article about internationalization and windows console here: http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/04/i18n-unicode-at-windows-command-prompt.html

Comment: http://ariely.info/Blog/tabid/83/EntryId/139/Windows-console-command-shell-Using-Local-Languages-En-US.aspx  chcp 862  and "courier new"

Answer (score 10):

Simply change the OutputEncoding:

```
Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1255");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
        Console.OutputEncoding = new UTF8Encoding();
        Console.WriteLine("\u05D0\u05D1");
        Console.WriteLine("אריאל");
        Console.WriteLine(new string("אריאל".Reverse().ToArray()));
```

works for me, maybe is just about removing the "false"?
this is working in my machine, except o.c. it writes the letters backwards, unless i use reverse

maybe you need to set the registry? run -> regedit and do this:
http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/technet/2013/06/11/%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9A-%D7%90%D7%A4%D7%A9%D7%A8-%D7%9C%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%A2%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%AA-%D7%91-powershell-console/

in the registry window rightclick choose new string.

Comment: The above seems not to work in the current version of powershell. I get an error on the first line.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong but I don't think the console supports UTF8.

Comment: Apparently it doesn't (see below).

Comment: The console has broken support for UTF-8. Windows has a codepage 65001 which you can set in the console via an API or from `cmd` by typing `chcp 65001`. However there is a bug in the Windows `WriteFile()` API when using this codepage which returns the number of Unicode characters written instead of the documented number of bytes written. If .net or C# compares this result to check if a write was successful then it will not work. This API bug is behind Perl, PHP, and Ruby not working under codepage 65001 and various problems in the Visual C runtime library.

Answer (score 0):

In case you just want it for short testing purposes and not to build an entire application, just use [`Debug.WriteLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline.aspx) that does support unicode (tested with heb chars only).