# In C#, when the exception is in Hebrew it reversed - How to solve?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console, hebrew

I started to learn C#, and When I had an error, It was in Hebrew, (And this is very cool), But the Hebrew was reversed.

I wanted to write here the error, but when I copied it - It suddenly was good, So I added a screenshot.

[The screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMCFj.png)

It happened when I tried to check if I can convert string to his ASCI value. The Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CSharpConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int x = int.Parse("a");
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }

    }
}
```

How can I see unreversed hebrew?

Thank's

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: OK. I did it. Thank you.

Comment: What do you want btw? Setting CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture and CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture to US English will help since the exception message will be in English, if you want to search the MSDN for explanation.

Comment: No. I want to see unreversed hebrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that displaying RTL in Windows Command Line is [problematic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27730700/529282). If you just want to see the exception "normally", you can try catching the message then reverse it. It doesn't work completely perfect, but should help.

```
try
{
   int x = int.Parse("a");
   Console.WriteLine(x);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
   Console.WriteLine(e.Message.Reverse().ToArray());
}
```

Comment: It worked great, but there is any way to make it allways unreversed?

Comment: Maybe. Plenty of other search result talk about changing code page, fonts etc, but the fact that your PC already show the Hebrew text at all (in my English Windows installation I have to done those to even get the Hebrew text instead of empty boxes) seems mean that's the best we can get. [Try this](http://ariely.info/Blog/tabid/83/EntryId/139/Windows-console-command-shell-Using-Local-Languages-En-US.aspx), I can't do it in my PC out of fear it will broke something, if it works perfectly, feel free to self-answer your question.

Comment: Ok. Thank you  very much